# How to use Token Replace only if the field has a value?

Tags: entities, theming, tokens

So I've been using token replace for a while now with great success in my themes.  For instance I'm using it currently to show the real name of an author by using

```
<?php print token_replace('[node:author:url]', array('node' => $node)); ?>">
```

The issue is that I've recently added a byline field in my storys and not all stories have a byline.  I've added it normally by using

```
<?php print token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node)); ?>
```

However when the field is empty it simply prints [node:field_byline] so I get stories like...

By: [node:field_byline]

Is there a way to check that the token field has something in it and only show that field if there's a value?  I'd like to just show nothing if there are now authors for the byline.  I tried using something like:

```
<? !empty [node:field_byline] ?>
```

but this hasnt worked.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I just used the following and it worked fine.

```
<?php if (token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node))): ?> <?php print token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node)); ?> <?php endif ?>
```

If there is a better way to do it I'm all ears! –  doodirock Jan 3 at 23:00

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'clear' option of token_replace to clear any tokens it can't find a replacement for.

```
<?php print token_replace('[node:author:url]', array('node' => $node), array('clear' => TRUE,); ?>">
```

As documented here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help?

```
<?php 
   $pos = strpos(token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node)), 'node:');

   if ($pos !== false) { // field is not empty
      print token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node));
   }
   else {
      print '';
   }
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything.  It doesn't toss any errors either however.  I just posts nothing at all no matter what.

Comment: Figured it out!  

I just used the following and it worked fine.

    <?php if (token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node))): ?>
    <?php print token_replace('[node:field_byline]', array('node' => $node)); ?>
    <?php endif ?>

If there is a better way to do it I'm all ears!